# Does the Poisson bivector give rise to an integrable distribution?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, foliations, poisson-geometry

I am reading the book [Lectures on the geometry of Poisson manifolds](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-0348-8495-2), by Izu Vaisman.

To a Poisson structure $\{\cdot,\cdot\}$ on a manifold $M$ we associate the Poisson bivector field $w\in\Gamma(\Lambda^2TM)$. We have

> **Lemma:** $[w,w]=0$

This follows directly from proposition 1.4 in the book. Here $[\cdot,\cdot]$ is the Schouten-Nijenhuis bracket.

Now let $w$ be given locally by $w=w_1\wedge w_2$. We compute
$$\begin{align}
[w,w] = & [w,w_1\wedge w_2]\\
= & [w,w_1]\wedge w_2 - w_1\wedge[w,w_2]\\
= & (-w_2\wedge[w_1,w_1] + w_1\wedge[w_2,w_1])\wedge w_2\\
& -w_1\wedge(-w_2\wedge[w_1,w_2] + w_1\wedge[w_2,w_2])\\
= & w_1\wedge[w_1\wedge w_2]\wedge w_2 + w_1\wedge w_2\wedge[w_1,w_2]\\
= & 2w\wedge[w_1,w_2]
\end{align}$$
This tells us that, whenever it is non-zero, $w$ locally spans an integrable distribution (by Frobenius' theorem, as we must have $[w_1,w_2] = 0$). In particular, if the Poisson structure comes from a symplectic structure then it is nowhere zero, and so we get a $2$-foliation of the manifold. Is this foliation studied somewhere? What is known about it?

---

**Edit:** I committed a rookie's error: in general $w$ is not of the form $w_1\wedge w_2$, but it is a sum of such pure terms.

My question becomes: are there interesting examples of Poisson structures on manifolds of the form we assumed above? Also, given a $2$-foliation of a manifold, is it possible to associate (canonically, if possible) a Poisson structure to it by considering the tangent space of the leaves?

Comment: Please make up your mind whether the tag [tag:foliations] is relevant or not. If you want more exposure for your question, consider setting a bounty.

Comment: When the poisson tensor comes from a symplectic form then you can look for Lagrangian foliations, that is, foliations the leaves of which are Lagrangian submanifolds. Obviously, there are topological obstructions, for example, on the 2-sphere there is a natural symplectic form, however, there is no non-singular 1-d foliation because the sphere is compact and has Euler characteristic 2

Comment: @Ilcapitano Yes, but this doesn't really answer the question I'm asking, i.e.: given a $1$-dim. foliation, can we construct a Poisson structure?

Comment: @Ilcapitano Also, similarly to what you say, on a Poisson manifold we can always construct a (not necessarily regular) foliation whose leaves are symplectic manifolds.

Comment: I suppose that the 2-foliation you are referring to is the one given by two conjugate vector fields of the local darboux basis of the symplectic form. You always get n couples of such 2-foliations, where n is the dimension of the manifold, however, I believe that thesE foliations are compatible only when the symplectic manifold is a cotangent bundle.